# Crash on "conda list", multiple egg files?

Tags: pip, anaconda

I got into a situation where `conda list` would crash every time on my Linux machine, no matter if I had an environment active or not. 
I don't know how it got into this state, but it seems to be connected with a package of my own, installed in editable mode with `pip install -e .` - the assertion text indicated as much (the lines referring to "`egg-info`".

Using `conda clean --all` had no effect, nor did upgrading Anaconda to the latest version (4.6.14, in this case).

The error always looked like this, more or less:

```
(envname) username@computername:~/projects/myproject$ conda list

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1003, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 82, in do_call
        exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main_list.py", line 142, in execute
        show_channel_urls=context.show_channel_urls)
      File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main_list.py", line 80, in print_packages
        show_channel_urls=show_channel_urls)
      File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main_list.py", line 45, in list_packages
        installed = sorted(PrefixData(prefix, pip_interop_enabled=True).iter_records(),
      File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/prefix_data.py", line 117, in iter_records
        return itervalues(self._prefix_records)
      File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/prefix_data.py", line 146, in _prefix_records
        return self.__prefix_records or self.load() or self.__prefix_records
      File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/prefix_data.py", line 70, in load
        self._load_site_packages()
      File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/prefix_data.py", line 261, in _load_site_packages
        python_record = read_python_record(self.prefix_path, af, python_pkg_record.version)
      File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/gateways/disk/read.py", line 245, in read_python_record
        pydist = PythonDistribution.init(prefix_path, anchor_file, python_version)
      File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/common/pkg_formats/python.py", line 76, in init
        return PythonEggLinkDistribution(prefix_path, anchor_file, python_version)
      File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/common/pkg_formats/python.py", line 416, in __init__
        anchor_full_path = get_dist_file_from_egg_link(anchor_file, prefix_path)
      File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/common/pkg_formats/python.py", line 915, in get_dist_file_from_egg_link
        assert len(egg_info_fnames) == 1, (egg_link_file, egg_info_fnames)
    AssertionError: ('lib/python3.6/site-packages/vqvae.egg-link', ['pytorch_wavenet.egg-info', 'vqvae.egg-info'])

`$ /home/username/anaconda3/bin/conda list`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=envname
                CONDA_EXE=/home/username/anaconda3/bin/conda
             CONDA_PREFIX=/home/username/anaconda3/envs/envname
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(envname)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/username/anaconda3/bin/python
               CONDA_ROOT=/home/username/anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
            DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
          LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
           MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
                     PATH=/home/username/anaconda3/bin:/home/username/anaconda3/envs/envname/bin:/home
                          /username/anaconda3/bin:/home/username/anaconda3/bin:/home/username/.cargo/bin:
                          /home/username/anaconda3/bin:/efs/bin:/efs/bin:/home/username/anaconda3/cond
                          abin:/home/username/anaconda3/bin:/efs/bin:/efs/bin:/home/username/.cargo/bi
                          n:/home/username/bin:/home/username/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bi
                          n:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:
                          /home/username/.fzf/bin
               PYTHONPATH=/efs/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
               WINDOWPATH=2

     active environment : envname
    active env location : /home/username/anaconda3/envs/envname
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/username/.condarc
 populated config files :
          conda version : 4.6.14
    conda-build version : 3.0.27
         python version : 3.6.8.final.0
       base environment : /home/username/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/username/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/username/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/username/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/username/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.14 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.8 Linux/4.15.0-47-generic ubuntu/18.04.2 glibc/2.27
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?
```

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have been able to get around the issue by simply removing (actually renaming) the `.egg-info` files the assertion refers to; then I needed to install the package in my environment again using `pip install -e .` in the relevant directory.

I still don't know what caused the error, and though I've sent the automated bug reports several times, don't know if the devs are going to fix it. So I thought I'd post this question in case it is of help to anybody else.